# Image loading taking too long

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, firebase-storage

I have started the development of an application with React, Redux and Firebase. But I have a problem when I am using Firebase Storage.

When I use my code:

```
getImage (image) {
    let { state } = this
    st.doGetArticlesImg(image).then((url) => {
      state[image] = url
      this.setState(state)
    }).catch((error) => {
       console.log(error);
    })
  }
```

My images load correctly but the loading is very long, they appear only 3 or 4 seconds after loading the page. And once in two they do not charge.

Surely a life cycle story of a component?

Comment: What's the filesize of those images?

Comment: Isn't a size problem. it's the way I download and display the images I think.

Look my article.js https://codesandbox.io/s/54lvw4m5x

My function is : 
```import { st } from './firebase';

export const doGetArticlesImg = (image) =>
  st.ref().child(/images/articles/${image}).getDownloadURL();```

Answer (score 0):

You get the state:

```
let { state } = this
```

And then modify it:

```
state[image] = url
```

Don't forget - you can't mutate the state. It seems like, after mutating the state react doesn't see the difference and doesn't call render(). I'd re-wrote this like:

```
this.setState({image: url})
```